# How to solve gradle sync while adding KMM shared module?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

**I am trying to add KMM shared module on an existing Android project. I used KMM plugin on Android Studio and after adding the module I have got the below sync error. Here are the logs of the error**

```
e: /shared/build.gradle.kts:6:8: An annotation argument must be a compile-time constant
e: /shared/build.gradle.kts:6:36: Unresolved reference: ExperimentalKotlinGradlePluginApi
e: /shared/build.gradle.kts:8:5: Unresolved reference: targetHierarchy

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/shared/build.gradle.kts' line: 6

* What went wrong:
Script compilation errors:

  Line 6: @OptIn(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.ExperimentalKotlinGradlePluginApi::class)
                 ^ An annotation argument must be a compile-time constant

  Line 6: @OptIn(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.ExperimentalKotlinGradlePluginApi::class)
                                             ^ Unresolved reference: ExperimentalKotlinGradlePluginApi

  Line 8:     targetHierarchy.default()
              ^ Unresolved reference: targetHierarchy
```

**And here is the gradle content of shared module build.gradle.kts**
djhsajkhdkjsahkdhksahdkasjhdkjashdkjhsad

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("com.android.library")
}

@OptIn(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.ExperimentalKotlinGradlePluginApi::class)
kotlin {
    targetHierarchy.default()

    android {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = "1.8"
            }
        }
    }
    
    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach {
        it.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "shared"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                //put your multiplatform dependencies here
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
            }
        }
    }
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.shared"
    compileSdk = 33
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 23
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What version of **org.jetbrains.kotlin.android** do you have?
Try 1.9.0, it should have what your config uses.

Comment: I have Kotlin 1.7.20 and gradle 7.4.2

Comment: Had the same issue, fixed with update to 1.9.0. Not sure if it's the only problem that leads to the error on your side.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by making the gradle like this

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("com.android.library")
}

kotlin {
    android {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = "1.8"
            }
        }
    }

    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach {
        it.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "shared"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                //put your multiplatform dependencies here
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
            }
        }
        val iosX64Main by getting
        val iosArm64Main by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Main by getting
        val iosMain by creating {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            iosX64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
        }
        val iosX64Test by getting
        val iosArm64Test by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Test by getting
        val iosTest by creating {
            dependsOn(commonTest)
            iosX64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
        }
    }
}

android {
    namespace = "com.etisalat.shared"
    compileSdk = 33
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 21
    }
}
```